# With xcode Version 5.0 and later there is build issue in mailcore 2 like below

Tags: ios

ld: framework not found IOKit clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I found the solution my question.  To solve this issue use following 2 commands, this command is One time and and it will works until you update xcode again, after updating xcode you will have to issue this command again. NOTE – in the first command please replace iPhoneOS8.2.sdk with your sdk version.                                                                      cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework

sudo ln -s Versions/A/IOKit .

Comment: 2. Open following files and replace iphoneos8.2 keyword with your sdk version.
build-mailcore2-ios.sh
build-mailcore2-macos.sh
gen-docs.sh
get-prebuilt.sh
prepare-ctemplate-ios.sh
prepare-ctemplate-macos.sh
prepare-icu4c-ios.sh
prepare-icu4c-macos.sh
prepare-ios.sh
prepare-libetpan-ios.sh
prepare-libetpan-macos.sh
prepare-mac.sh
prepare-tidy-ios.sh
prepare.sh